# NilClass - What does Ruby inheritance really mean?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, syntax

Newbie question.

I assumed that "inheritance" is the basic feature of Ruby. And every class inherits methods from both its `.class` and `.superclass`.

Since `NilClass` has `Class` and `Object` as its `.class` and `.superclass`, you'd assume `NilClass` to have all their methods.

Then my brain exploded when I saw this:

```rb
>> NilClass.class
=> Class
>> NilClass.class.methods - NilClass.methods
=> [:nesting, :new]
>> NilClass.superclass
=> Object
>> NilClass.superclass.methods - NilClass.methods
=> [:new]
```

What is going on?

Can anyone explain what's really going on underlying the whole inheritance mechanism in Ruby?

What does inheritance really mean in Ruby?

Comment: Which bit of this is surprising ?

Comment: That `NilClass` does not have all methods of `Class` or `Object`, even when it has them as class and superclass?

Comment: You may want to watch Dave Thomas's lecture entitled, [The Ruby Object Model](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=X2sgQ38UDVY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assumed that "inheritance" is the basic feature of Ruby. And every class inherits methods from both its `.class` and `.superclass`.

That's correct. Every class inherits methods from its superclass, which is `Object` by default.

```
class Foo
end

Foo.superclass #=> Object
```

`Foo` responds to `Object`'s class methods and `Foo` instances respond to `Object`'s instance methods.

Furthermore, every class is an instance of `Class` and therefore responds to `Class`' instance methods (just like `Foo` instances respond to `Foo`'s instance methods):

```
Foo.class #=> Class

Foo.method(:new)
#=> #<Method: Class#new>
```

Calling `Foo.new` simply invokes [`Class#new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-new).

> Since `NilClass` has `Class` and `Object` as its `.class` and `.superclass`, you'd assume `NilClass` to have all their methods.

It would, but `nil` is a singleton, i.e. there's only one `nil` instance and you can't create any other instances. This is achieved (among other things) by *undefining* `new`. From Ruby's [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/object.c#L3374):

```c
rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cNilClass), "new");
```

You could do the same in plain Ruby:

```
Foo.singleton_class.send(:undef_method, :new)
Foo.new
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Foo:Class
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the real thing bugs me :-)